# Keep website CSS from interfering with tooltip CSS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I'm working on a browser script that scans a page for keywords, highlights them, and when the user hovers over them - creates a tooltip that gets filled using AJAX and PHP. The only problem I've run into is that the CSS of the website the tooltips are displayed on is interfering with the CSS of the tooltip content.

The tooltip uses an `<img>`, `<p>` and `<table>` with `<tr>` and `<td>`. My PHP file echoes these elements back with ID's which I have styled in my CSS file. My CSS displays properly on some sites like Wikipedia, but others mess up the padding/margins/alignment. For example, certain websites may align `<td>` center, while I would like it aligned left. I have already added "!important" to many of the ID's used.

**Question**: How do I keep a website's CSS from interfering with the styles of my tooltip?

Comment: You mean your tooltips have the same IDs as the webpage itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is to use a `id` for your tooltip container.

You just need to keep in mind that `id` have to be unique. So you must not have two tooltips on your page.

```html
<div id="my-tooltip-2986234">
    the content of the tooltip
</div>
```

Then for your `css` file your create something like this:

```css
#my-tooltip-2986234 * {
     /*reset all style properties here (you can take this of a css reset script)*/
}
```

Because `id` a have a higher *weight*  then rules without an `id` this should overwrite all stylings of the foreign page inside of your tooltip container.

You will also need to prefix all your rules for the tooltip with that `id`.

```css
#my-tooltip-2986234 a {
     /*style for your a*/
}
```

You indeed could still have problems with `!important` rules of the foreign site. But creating your styling code that way would minimize the conflicts. Your can still think of adding `!important` rules to your rules. But at least for the things I created prefixing the rules with an `id` was sufficient.

Another solution - but not as elegant as the one above - is to create an `iframe` container where you write your content to. That way you would have complete sandboxing of your css rules. But because I didn't use `iframe` for a long time I don't know right now where the pitfalls in the various browsers are (You need to create an `iframe` without a `src`, because of cross domain policies, which used to cause problems in some browsers).